# How do I remove duplicate objects from a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I've been trying to do this for hours and only one question on this site came close but all the answers were used concepts far more complex than I can understand yet and I couldn't edit them to fit my code.

Here is the map:

```
private Map<Integer, Item> inventory;
public Inventory() {
    inventory = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Here are the objects that were added:

```
Inventory inv = new Inventory();
Item obj1 = new Potion("Test", 20, "TESTING");
Item obj2 = new Potion("TES2", 30, "ANOTHER TEST");
Item obj3 = new Potion("TesT 3", 220, "TESTS");
Item sword = new Weapon("TES T 4", 42, "t");
Item weapon3 = new Weapon("dupetest", 100, "test dupes.");
Item waraxe = new Weapon("6th test", 2050, "a test for the inv");
Item bow = new Weapon("7 teST", 12, "test number 7");
Item weapon = new Weapon("dupetest", 100, "test dupes.");
Item weapon2 = new Weapon("dupetest", 100, "test dupes.");
inv.add(obj1, obj2, weapon3, obj3, sword, waraxe, bow, weapon, weapon2);
```

Note, all objects are of type Item and note that weapon3, weapon and weapon2 are the exact same object: same hashcode, state, everything.

Here are the hashCode() and equals() method for Item:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + value;
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Item other = (Item) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (value != other.value)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

I have tried a lot, my closest only removed one of the objects not both.

Adding code:

```
public void add(Item... objects) {
    for(Item obj : objects) {
        inventory.put(obj.getKey(), obj);
    }
}
```

Here's `getKey();`

```
private String name;
private int value;
private String description;
private static Integer key = 0;
private Integer individualKey;
public Item(String name, int value, String description) {
    setName(name);
    setValue(value);
    setDescription(description);
    key++;
    individualKey = key;
}
```

Here's some more

```
public Integer getKey() {
    return individualKey;
}
```

Comment: What about first sorting the hashmap and then looping through them and checking if the next item is the same then the current item? If that is the case remove the item?

Comment: If by duplicate, you mean that, for example, `weapon` and `weapon2` are logically equivalent, then you're going to have to add code to your `Inventory#equals` method to check for this, and the other cases you have in mind.

Comment: Where is the code to remove duplicates?

Comment: Where is the code that adds anything to the map?

Comment: what does  the add method do? A lot of the picture is missing to answer your question.

Comment: I removed it because it was wrong. Basically it looped through my hashmap and set two temporary variables. It set one to the first item, then looped the second one straight through and checked if it was equal each time and each time it was it increased an int by one and if the int at the end was bigger than one, it removed temp1 from the list.

Comment: I'll edit some code in

Comment: They might all share the same `Item` base class/interface, but they're not all the same class so `equals()` will return false for different implementations.

Comment: The duplicates are all of the weapon class

Comment: okay - what does `getKey()` do?  Post the code.

Comment: `public Integer getKey() {
  return individualKey;
  }`

Comment: here are the variables

Comment: `private String name;
 private int value;
 private String description;
 private static Integer key = 0;
 private Integer individualKey;`

Answer (score 0):

This could work but I would look at making your add method prevent it in the first place and figure out why you are using a HashMap rather than some other collection.

```
List<Item> al = new ArrayList<Item>(inv.values());

Set<Item> hs = new LinkedHashSet<>(al);

hs.addAll(al);
al.clear();
al.addAll(hs);
inv.clear()
for (Item i : hs) inv.put(i.getKey(),i);
```